# Change SCNNode origin point without changing pivot

Tags: scenekit, scnnode

I’m trying to change the origin point of my node from being in the node’s center to being at the “top left” of my node (I’m using an orthographic project and trying to re-implement 2D “views” using nodes, so I’m only displaying one face of eg a plane).

According to the `SCNNode` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408044-pivot), changing a node’s `pivot` point allows you to change its origin for subnodes. However, it *also* changes the origin for rotation and scaling subnodes, which is not what I want to do. I want my origin to be at the top left, but I want to be able to rotate / scale my node about its center point.

If I place a subnode at `(0, 0, 0)` I want it to appear in the top-left corner of my node. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an ***auxiliary*** `emptyNode` for setting a pivot's offset only But rotation and scale will be occurred around a center of geometry using another node.

```
let sphereGeo = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
sphereGeo.segmentCount = 4
sphereGeo.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.lightGray
let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeo)

let emptyNode = SCNNode()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(emptyNode)
emptyNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

emptyNode.simdPivot.columns.3.x = 5

let action = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi, 
                                                  around: SCNVector3(0,1,0), 
                                                duration: 1))
sphereNode.runAction(action)
```